# Deploying Gatsby static assets on an Express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, gatsby

I'm fairly new to Gatsby and React, but I'm looking to deploy the static assets generated by a Gatsby build on an Express server. If I import the Public folder generated by 'gatsby build' into the server directory, and use the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('./public/index')
});

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Running on port 8080")
});
```

The homepage is just blank. My question is, how can I configure my Express app and Gatsby (and therefore React and React Router) so that the Gatsby site will run through my Express app?

Comment: From what I know, Gatsby does React's SSR so all of your routes are static HTML pages.

Comment: Hi Rikin, thanks for this - does that mean that what I'm trying to do is redundant? What I want ultimately to do is deploy the Gatsby front end on EC2 with an express backend

Comment: I'm also exploring Gatsby so I'm not best resource to comment on it, but Gatsby setup already comes with node/webpack configuration and to be honest from what I think it may be redundant as you may only want to point gatsby setting to your API for getting data.

Comment: OK thanks, so essentially Gatsby provides its own server?

Comment: Yes, from what I know so far, I tried this deployment: https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-portfolio-cara